# How do I extend a pandas DataFrame by repeating the last row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, and would like to extend it by repeating the last row n times.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = date_range('1/1/2014', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(4, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
n = 3
for i in range(n):
    df = df.append(df[-1:])
```

so df is

```
            A  B  C  D
2013-01-01  1  0  0  0
2013-01-02  0  1  0  0
2013-01-03  0  0  1  0
2013-01-04  0  0  0  1
2013-01-04  0  0  0  1
2013-01-04  0  0  0  1
2013-01-04  0  0  0  1
```

Is there a better way to do this without the for loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an alternate (fancy indexing) way to do it:

```
df.append( df.iloc[[-1]*3] )

Out[757]: 
            A  B  C  D
2014-01-01  1  0  0  0
2014-01-02  0  1  0  0
2014-01-03  0  0  1  0
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use nested `concat` operations, the inner one will concatenate your last row 3 times and we then concatenate this with your orig df:

```
In [181]:

dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(4, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
pd.concat([df,pd.concat([df[-1:]]*3)])
Out[181]:
            A  B  C  D
2014-01-01  1  0  0  0
2014-01-02  0  1  0  0
2014-01-03  0  0  1  0
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
```

This could be put into a function like so:

```
In [182]:

def repeatRows(d, n=3):
    return pd.concat([d]*n)

pd.concat([df,repeatRows(df[-1:], 3)])
Out[182]:
            A  B  C  D
2014-01-01  1  0  0  0
2014-01-02  0  1  0  0
2014-01-03  0  0  1  0
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
2014-01-04  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, without using any index or multiple concat, is by using **tail()** and the **unpack operator**. Notice that the method **append** is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecated-dataframe-append-and-series-append).

```
pd.concat([df, *[df.tail(1)]*3])
```

Therefore, to repeat the last *n* rows *d* times:

```
pd.concat([df, *[df.tail(n)]*d])
```

[**tail(n)**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) returns the last n elements (by default n=5).

The **unpack operator** ('*') allows you to unpack a sequence or iterable into separate variables, for example:

```
def sum_var(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

numbers = [1, 2, 3]

sum_result = sum_var(*numbers)
```